# What kind of a 'sentence' is it?

Tags: sentence-structure, writing

I encountered a very interesting sentence on the Red Bull distribution company website. I'd like to know what kind of a writing technique, or maybe a grammar structure was used to express the second (highlighted) sentence. I noticed that the object was omitted in this sentence, but I have no idea what is going on here.

Red Bull North America, Inc. (RBNA) has been giving wings to US consumers since 1997.***Based in Santa Monica, California, RBNA operates as a subsidiary of Red Bull GmbH, responsible for all sales and marketing activities related to Red Bull Energy Drinks across the United States and Canada.***

Comment: It's headlinese: some normal sentences have been put into a blender and one or two bits seem to be missing. It is not a good model to study correct sentence construction.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but I think the sentence is not odd to me. The main clause: RBNA[subject]+ operates[predicate] + as a subsidiary of Red Bull GmbH[complement].